# i have added a searchbox to find details, i want if name is in Uppercase and i entered lowercase results should come

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, oracle11g

Thats my action method in controller for details:

```
public ActionResult Details(string Search)
    {
        List<MemberDetail> members = new List<Models.MemberDetail>();
        OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionDHC"].ToString();
        connection.Open();

        if (Session["Email"] == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            if (Search != null )
            {
                OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                string query = "SELECT * FROM MEMBER where NAME like '%" + Search + "%' ";
                command.CommandText = query;
                OracleDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    MemberDetail memberDetail = new MemberDetail();
                    memberDetail.Name = dataReader["NAME"].ToString();
                    memberDetail.DOB = dataReader["Age"].ToString();
                    memberDetail.Gender = dataReader["GENDER"].ToString();
                    memberDetail.Fees = dataReader["FEES"].ToString();
                    memberDetail.Package = dataReader["PACKAGE"].ToString();
                    members.Add(memberDetail);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                string query = "SELECT * FROM MEMBER";
                command.CommandText = query;
                OracleDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    MemberDetail memberDetail = new MemberDetail();
                    memberDetail.Name = dataReader["NAME"].ToString();
                    memberDetail.DOB = dataReader["Age"].ToString();
                    memberDetail.Gender = dataReader["GENDER"].ToString();
                    memberDetail.Fees = dataReader["FEES"].ToString();
                    memberDetail.Package = dataReader["PACKAGE"].ToString();
                    members.Add(memberDetail);
                }
            }
        }
        return View(members);
    }
```

results only come if i enter the Starting letter in capital but i want if i enter a small letter results should be displayed.What changes should be done in it.

Comment: Use bind variables!! (This is not an answer to the case issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove case sensitivity from the query. For this you can use the below query and change the above line with the below.

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM MEMBER where Lower(NAME) like '%" + Search.ToLower() + "%' ";
```